# Page Title Prefix in single store mode not working

Tags: magento2, admin-panel

I am using Magento 2.2.5. When I enable single store mode the `Page Title Prefix` not working. But If I disable single store mode than it's fine. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change that using Database use this query to search the value in core_config_data table and look for "Store" Scope you can change prefix/suffix there. Clear cache and it should work.

`SELECT * FROM core_config_data where path like '%design/head/title_%';`